# Mongodb find documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB instance which contains a translation of texts:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57c68ba415f4d42b6ecd9ee7"),
        "en" : "Adana (pronounced [aˈda.na]) is a major city in southern Turkey. The city is situated on the Seyhan river, 35 km (22 mi) inland from the Mediterranean Sea, in south-central Anatolia. It is the administrative seat of the Adana Province and has a population of 1.7 million,[1] making it the fifth most populous city in Turkey. Adana-Mersin polycentric metropolitan area, with a population of 3 million, stretches over 70 km (43 mi) east-west and 25 km (16 mi) north-south; encompassing the cities of Mersin, Tarsus and Adana.",
        "sw" : "Adana (Kigiriki Άδανα) ni mji mkubwa katika nchi ya Uturuki. Kwa mujibu wa sensa iliyofanyika mwaka wa 2000, mji una wakazi wapatao 1,130,710 waishio huko,[2] na kuufanya kuwa mmoja kati ya miji mitano mikubwa ya Uturuku (baada ya Istanbul, Ankara, İzmir na Bursa). Mwaka wa 2006 mji wa Adana umekadiriwa kufikia iadadi ya wakazi wapatao 1,271,894. Huu ndiyo mji mkuu wa Mkoa wa Adana."
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57c68ba915f4d42b6ecd9eea"),
        "en" : "Addis Ababa or Addis Abeba (the spelling used by the official Ethiopian Mapping Authority),(Amharic: አዲስ አበባ? Addis Abäba IPA: [adˈdis ˈabəba] ( listen), \"new flower\"; Oromo: Finfinne,[3][4] [fɪnˈfɪ́n.nɛ́] \"Natural Spring(s)\"), is the capital and largest city of Ethiopia. Finfinne is its Oromo name. It has a population of 3,384,569 according to the 2007 population census, with annual growth rate of 3.8%. This number has been increased from the originally published 2,738,248 figure and appears to be still largely underestimated.[2][5]",
        "sw" : "Addis Ababa (pia Addis Abeba; kwa Kiamhara አዲስ አበባ, \"Ua Jipya\"; kwa Kioromo Finfinne) ni mji mkuu wa Ethiopia na wa Umoja wa Afrika."
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57c68bab15f4d42b6ecd9eec"),
        "en" : "Adelaide of Italy (931 – 16 December 999), also called Adelaide of Burgundy, was the second wife of Holy Roman Emperor Otto the Great[2] and was crowned as the Holy Roman Empress with him by Pope John XII in Rome on February 2, 962. Empress Adelaide was perhaps the most prominent European woman of the 10th century; she was regent of the Holy Roman Empire as the guardian of her grandson in 991-995.[2]",
        "sw" : "Adelaide wa Italia (takriban 931 – 16 Desemba, 999) alikuwa binti wa Rudolf II, mfalme wa Burgundia. Kwanza aliolewa na Lothar, mfalme wa Italia. Alipofariki Lothar, Adelaide aliolewa na Otto I, mfalme wa Ujerumani. Aliishi maisha matakatifu. Sikukuu yake ni 16 Desemba."
}
```

What I would like to do is to select one specific record. For example I expect to select the last record by doing this:

```
db.wiki.find({"sw": "Adelaide wa Italia"}).pretty();
```

But the mongo shell returns nothing.

Indeed, I know that I can create an index and do something like:

```
db.wiki.find({$text: {$search: "\"Adelaide wa Italia\""}}).pretty();
```

which indeed returns the record as expected.

What am I doing wrong in the non-index searching please?

Comment: Your query is right and provided you have the text index you should find it. I just tried to be sure and found the last document.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Yes the text index is OK, but I was wondering how to do the same without an index in place

Comment: Oh I didn't notice you were doing the non-index version. IMHO you shouldn't do that without an index. If you would anyway, probably you would also want to add some regex options like ignore case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should use search with [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/):

```
db.wiki.find({"sw": /Adelaide wa Italia/}).pretty();
```

The way you are doing it by:

```
db.wiki.find({"sw": "Adelaide wa Italia"}).pretty();
```

you simply tell Mongo to return you all documents where `sw` is equal to `Adelaide wa Italia` but you want to get all documents which contains this phrase in `sw` field instead.

Comment: He is using text index and text search.

Comment: I see what you  meant there. I now understand tha the initial query was searching where the entire string is "Adelaide wa Italia"